# orbits of matrices in L(F)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a formula for calculating the cardinalities of orbits of $A\in L(F)$ under conjugation of $\text{GL}_2(F)$? I know that $|G|=|G_x||Gx|$, but somthing other than this? I am asking this since I have some difficulties determining the cardinality of the orbit of

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1
  \end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by $L(F)$ you mean $L(F^2)=M_{2,2}(F)$ then you should definitely use the formula :
$$|G|=|G_x||Gx| $$

Because $G_x$ is (in the case of a conjugation action) the centralizer of $x$. If :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the centralizer of $A$ is easily seen to be the set of matrices that can be written :

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix} $$

Where $a,b\in F^*$ (to show this, you just need to show that if $z$ commutes with $A$ then $z$ will leave invariant the eigenspaces of $A$). Now you have $|G_A|=(|F|-1)^2$ so $|GA|=...$